# SQLALchemy-Utils: Use '~' operator with LTree

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query Postgres materialized path view(ltree) using Flask,[SQLAlchemy-Utils](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils) and Flask-SQLAlchemy. [SQLAlchemy-Util Docs](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#sqlalchemy_utils.primitives.ltree.Ltree) shows the usage of '==', '!=' operators using LTree. How can i use '~' operator?

I saw the code in sqlalchemy_utils/ltree.py:

```
class comparator_factory(types.Concatenable.Comparator):
    def ancestor_of(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return self.op('@>')(expression.cast(other, ARRAY(LtreeType)))
        else:
            return self.op('@>')(other)

    def descendant_of(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return self.op('<@')(expression.cast(other, ARRAY(LtreeType)))
        else:
            return self.op('<@')(other)

    def lquery(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return self.op('?')(expression.cast(other, ARRAY(LQUERY)))
        else:
            return self.op('~')(other)

    def ltxtquery(self, other):
        return self.op('@')(other)
```

This is subclass of LtreeType.

For a simple `==`, i am using :

```
Model.query.filter(Model.path == LTree('1.2')).all()
```

But using this expression throws validation error:

```
Model.query.filter(Model.path == LTree('~1.2')).all()
```

How can i format above expression in a valid SQLALchemy query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with this piece of code.

Courtesy Github-Issues: [SQLAlchemy-Util Issues (253)](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/253)

```
 from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
 from sqlalchemy_utils.types.ltree import LQUERY

 custom_lquery = '*.some.pattern'
 Model.query.filter(Model.path.lquery(expression.cast(custom_lquery, LQUERY))).all()
```